# It's possible to use value from input type text for query data from mysqli php directly by not to use ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

It's possible to use value from input type text for query data from mysqli php directly by not to use ajax ?

From bottom code it's possible to use value from input id `fingerprint_check` for query data from mysqli php directly by not to use ajax ?

```
<input id="fingerprint_check" name="fingerprint_check"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById('fingerprint_check').value = "1234567890";
</script>

<?PHP
    $results = $db_mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE fingerprint_check = 'value in input id fingerprint_check '");
    if($results) 
    { 
        if($results->num_rows === 0)
        {
            echo "1";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "2";
        }       
    }   
?>
```

Comment: The PHP is only on the server. Once the page has loaded it is gone. You could use a standard HTML form or you could use AJAX. The data has to make it to your server though to be processed.

Comment: No, you have to use AJAX (or standard form submission) as JS runs on the client and PHP on the server.